# Unexpected links generated when creating a folder hierarchy in blob storage

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, python-3.9

I have a Python script that loads files into a folder hierarchy in an Azure storage container/blob storage. The folder hierarchy structure is  High-level-folder_name/Year/Month/Day/filename.json. For example : data/Scanner/2022/07/15/scanner23_30_45_21.json

New folders are added to the hierarchy, based on the current date. My code works, but for some reason a folder with a link to the top of the container hierarchy is also created at each level of the folder structure. See image below

[image]
My code is below. Any ideas on what is causing the links to upper level of the hierarchy would be appreciated.

*I have a feeling this issue is linked to the Blob service being based on a flat storage scheme (rather than hierarchical scheme). Link here [With help of Python, how can I create dynamic subfolder under Azure Blobstorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71313065/with-help-of-python-how-can-i-create-dynamic-subfolder-under-azure-blobstorage)

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime
import json
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

#file name
datetime_string = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%I_%M_%S_%p")
#folders that the files foes in Year -> months -Filename.json
year_utc = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y")
month_utc = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%m")
filename_prefix =f"Scanner/{year_utc}/{month_utc}/{datetime_string}.json"
data = json.dumps("test_content_of_file",indent = 4)
blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="Connectionstringetc",
                                    container_name="data", blob_name= filename_prefix)                                         
blob.upload_blob(data, overwrite=False)
```

Comment: This is just to go one level up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when creating a folder hierarchy in blob storage ***it is the default underlined structure of azure blob storage***

[image]

Azure made available this UI design ***that links helps to move one upper level of folder*** it analysis the previous path and move advances to the subsequent path. which we can't change or alter the view as default one.