# Azure lifecycle policy for containers with dynamic directory names and blobs inside them

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-policy

I want to configure an azure lifecycle policy to containers such that the blobs are moved to cool tier after some specific time, but the blobs are inside dynamically created directory inside container, e.g

mycontainer/test-123/blob1.pdf;
mycontainer/test-98765/blob2.pdf;
mycontainer/test-qw9876/blob3.pdf

where "mycontainer/test-" remains same for all the blobs, but file names are dynamic, we need to apply the policy for the all blobs under the container "mycontainer/test-*".

Note: * values will be dynamically generated.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to provide details - you haven't shown any code or other details describing the issue you're having.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add the blobs in the container and move to cool tiers I'm getting result successfully without any dynamical creation

**In your storage account -> use storage browser -> under blob container -> create container -> *upload files directly in the container***

[image]

After configuring an azure lifecycle policy to containers moving blobs to cool tier ***try to remove the character and update the rule***

[image]

[image]

***Here, blobs are moved to cool tier without any changes even after specific time***

[image]

For reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-policy-configure?tabs=azure-portal

[Unexpected links generated when creating a folder hierarchy in blob storage - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72988814/unexpected-links-generated-when-creating-a-folder-hierarchy-in-blob-storage/72998199#72998199)

Comment: You're answering a question that doesn't have any specifics, other than a general requirement.